# how to create update checkbox value from database to check on checkbox using php javascript

Tags: javascript, php, database, checkbox, mysqli

Give me some examples how to update checkbox form by retrieve value from database and do
if value=1 i want input type="checkbox" name="apple" value="1" Apple=checked.

```
<form action="update.php" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="apple" value="1">Apple <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="orange" value="2">Orange <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="banana" value="3">Banana <br>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Save</button>
```

Comment: check this https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

First of fetch the query result loop that array and show them in checkboxes Dynamically

```
  <?php
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn,'SELECT name  FROM fruits') or     die(mysql_error());
    echo "<ul>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_BOTH)){

    echo "<li> <input type='checkbox' name='fruits[]' value='".$row['name']."'></li>"
        .$row['name'];
}//end while

    echo"</ul>";
```